# Kubernetes EKS deployment set soft node affinity to split pods 50/50 per nodegroup

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment

I have an `EKS cluster` with two `nodegroups` each in different `AZ`. One `deployment` `Deployment1` is running on 2 `namespaces` for redundancy, one copy per `namespace` and each of them run in separate `AZs`/`nodegroup`. Also there is another `deployment` `Deployment2` that does not have any `node affinity` set and K8s manages where pods get scheduled.
Both `deployments` are huge with lots of pods. I have a subnet of 250 IPs available to me for each node group.

The problem is that while `Deployment1` is fine on it's own, and gets split almost equally per `AZ/Nodegroup`, the `Deployment2` tends to schedule most pods in one of the `nodegroups` and that ends when there are no more IPs available. This is a problem for `Deployment1` since one `namespace` of it is tied to that `nodegroup` and no new pods can be scheduled there if load changes.

Can I somehow balance `Deployment2` so it has 'soft affinity' that would split it 50/50 per each nodegroup, but if needed, can schedule pods in the other nodegroup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Kubernetes 1.19 or later you can use `topologySpreadConstraints`, adding this to the pod template:

```
topologySpreadConstraints:
  - maxSkew: 1
    topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
    whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
    labelSelector:
      matchLabels:
        foo: bar
```

where `maxSkew` define how uneven pods can be scheduled, `topologyKey` is the key of node labels and the `labelSelector` matches a label of your deployment. See [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/)

If your on an older Kubernetes version, you can look at pod anti affinity.

Comment: Thank you, this works great and exactly what I needed. I just have one more issue but I guess it's not directly related to the question. When I first deploy `Deployment2` it does not really follow topology spread constraints, because as the new nodes come up pods will go to first node that comes up regardless of AZ, because I am using `whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway` . Then I have to manually increase node size in one group and kill pods in the other one to get them balanced again.

Comment: Easiest would probably be to do a `kubectl rollout restart deploy Deployment2`, so all pods of that deployment will get rolling restarted, honoring the zones. That should distributed them without interupting ongoing traffic. If you increase nodes manually that could simply be a second step.